# how to access List of lists concurrently

Tags: java, multithreading, arraylist

I have a List of Lists , what i want to do is create threads which reads objects(list) and removes it from the "sharedList" , how can make the list threadsafe ? am using synchronizedList , but what if a thread removed and object while another thread was reading another object ? as .remove shifts the objects to the left ....

filler class

```
public class DataFetcher implements Runnable {

    Session session = null;
    Criteria criteria = null;
    private List<Parts> partList = null;




    public DataFetcher() {

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        // while(true)
        List newPartList =getNParts(DBIndexGuard.getAllowedListSize());
        SharedList.addPartList(newPartList);


    }

    public List<Parts> getNParts(int listSize) {

        try {
            session = HibernateUtils.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            criteria = ....
            // *********** SYNCHRONIZATION OCCURS HERE ********************//
            criteria.setFirstResult(DBIndexGuard.getNextIndex());
            criteria.setMaxResults(listSize);
            partList = criteria.list();



        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        } finally {

            session.close();
        }
        return partList;
    }

}
```

sharedList class

```
public class SharedList {

    private static final List<List<Parts>> sharedList = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList());

    public List<List<Parts>> SharedList() {

        return sharedList;

    }

    static synchronized void addPartList(List partList) {
        sharedList.add(partList);
    }

    static synchronized List getPartList(int index) {

        return sharedList.get(index);
    }

    static synchronized void removePartList(int index) {
        sharedList.remove(index);
    }
}
```

the worker thread

```
public class Finder implements Runnable {
    private List<Parts> partList = null;

    public Finder () {
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        operateOnList(partList);
    }

    public void operateOnList(List<Parts> partList) {
        for (Parts part : partList) {

        }

    }
}
```

I will be creating multi finders to work on the sharedList

Comment: We can't comment on the thread-safety of some code without seeing any single line of it. Post code.

Comment: The first thing you should realize is that Hibernate entities aren't thread-safe, and thus aren't supposed to be accessed from more than one thread.

Comment: yea it's okey , suppose it's only 1 thread for hibernate for now , how can i manage  read/write operations on the sharedList concurrently ?

Comment: It's not only one thread for Hibernate, since you're storing Hibernate entities in a shared list. The sharedList is synchronized, so it's thread-safe. What's not is the list it contains. But it's unclear if you access them from multiple threads.

Comment: what am doing is ... getting pages from database , store them in a "small list" and store the small list in a bigger list , threads are reading for the big list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList())` returns a Thread-Safe wrapper of collection where access to each method is locked on wrapper instance which means only one thread can call any methods on this wrapper. But when you want to iterate over list and perform some mutable operations then you need to synchronize iterations over this list on wrapper object, from javadoc:

```
It is imperative that the user manually synchronize on the returned list when iterating over it:

        List list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList());
                 ...
             synchronized (list) {
                 Iterator i = list.iterator(); // Must be in synchronized block
                 while (i.hasNext())
                     foo(i.next());
             }

Failure to follow this advice may result in non-deterministic behavior.
```

If it's crucial to iterate over list cuncurently then `CopyOnWriteArrayList` might be a way to go. It allows you to have multiple threads iterating over same list but I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for, because:

> A thread-safe variant of ArrayList in which all mutative operations (add, set, and so on) are implemented by making a fresh copy of the underlying array.

Which means that all changes to the list will not be visible to threads that are already iterating over it (should be fine for you unless list is not exactly what you want). From your short description I understood that you are looking for a collection which will hold some objects and you want to have multiple threads accessing this collection and polling objects one after another for some kind of processing. If my assumption is correct then you should implement this kind of functionality using a Queue rather than List (for example a [BlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html)).